# Sending command-line parameters when using node-windows to create a service

Tags: node.js, windows, service, node-windows

I've built some custom middleware on Node.js for a client which runs great in user space, but I want to make it a service.

I've accomplished this using node-windows, which works great, but the client has occasional large bursts of data so I'd like to allocate a little more memory using the `--max-old-space-size` command line parameter. Unfortunately, I don't see how to configure that in my service set-up wrapper for node-windows.

Any suggestions?

FWIW, I'm also thinking about changing how I parse the data, e.g. treating it more as a stream, but since this is the first time I've used Node and the project is going live in a couple of days, I'm hoping to find a quick and dirty option that'll get us to an up-and-running status easily, to be adjusted later.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an issue for this feature here: https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/issues/100 . Still open though.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any other service-creation packages which (a) support this and (b) are as easy to use? The other one I used required Python 2.7 and .NET 2.5 SDK to be installed and was just too hack-ish to work. Exploring all my options...

Answer (score 0):

Use node-windows v0.1.14 or higher. The ability to add flags was [merged](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/pull/160) in this version. The more appropriate issue related to this is https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/issues/159.